# Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::url does not exist

Tags: laravel, methods, routes, controller

the problem is that route is not visible :

```
// Front routes
Route::namespace('App\Https\Comtrollers\Front')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index']);

    // Listing/categories routes
    $catUrls = Category::select('url')->where('status',1)->get()->pluck('url')->toArray();
    // dd($catUrls);
    foreach ($catUrls as $key => $url) {
        Route::get('/'.$url ,[ProductController::class, 'listing']);

    }


});
```

```
class ProductController extends Controller {
    public function listing() {                                                                         
      // echo "test"; die;
      $url =  Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->url();
    }
}
```

test is working fine , but  route is not visible...

Comment: What is the content of `$catUrls`?

Comment: these are categories and sub categories -  at front end user will be able to choose subcategory and at front end will be visible only that subcategoy content
array:10 [▼ // routes/web.php:129
  0 => "men"
  1 => "women"
  2 => "kids"
  3 => "mobiles"
  4 => "mobiles"
  5 => "shirts"
  6 => "shirts"
  7 => "tops"
  8 => "test"
  9 => "test"
]

Comment: the thing is that the Symbol '$key' is declared but not used ,  so foreach ($catUrls as $key => $url) not working,   and next in productController  Symbol '$url' is declared but not used...

Comment: side note .. call `pluck('url')` instead of `get()->pluck('url')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that:

```
$catUrls = Category::select('url')->where('status',1)->pluck('url')->toArray();
    
Route::get('/{category}', [ProductController::class, 'listing'])->whereIn('category', $catUrls);
```

Comment: not working buddy...